# Sockets en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Tengo un problema con `sockets` en `python`. Aquí mi código:

Archivo `server.py`:

```
import subprocess
import socket

def run_command(command):
    process = subprocess.run(command.split(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE,)
    return process.stdout

skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
skt.bind(('localhost', 9999))

skt.listen(5)

while True:
    client_socket, addr = skt.accept()

    while True:
        received = client_socket.recv(1024)
        client_socket.send(run_command(received))
```

Archivo `client.py`:

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('localhost', 9999))

while True:
        client_socket.send(
            input('>> ').encode('utf-8')
        )

        received = client_socket.recv(2024)
        print(received)

client_socket.close()
```

El propósito es poder ejecutar comandos, pero al momento de hacerlo se presenta el primer problema, el problema consta en como imprime la salida de la terminal, ejemplo:

```
>> ls
b'client.py\nproyect.py\nserver.py\ntest.py\n'
>> apt
b'apt 1.6.11 (amd64)\nUso: apt [opciones] orden\n\napt es un gestor de paquetes de l\xc3\xadnea de \xc3\xb3rdenes y proporciona \xc3\xb3rdenes\npara la b....
```

¿Como se hace para poder imprimir de forma "normal", por así decirlo, la salida de la terminal y que no se vea feo?.

También me encuentro con el problema, de que, al ejecutar muchos comandos ocurre un error. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
>> ls
b'client.py\nproyect.py\nserver.py\ntest.py\n'
>> ls
b'client.py\nproyect.py\nserver.py\ntest.py\n'
>> ls
b'client.py\nproyect.py\nserver.py\ntest.py\n'
>> ls
b'client.py\nproyect.py\nserver.py\ntest.py\n'
>> cd  ..
b''
>> ls
b''
>> ls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 8, in <module>
    input('>> ').encode('utf-8')
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

¿Hay una manera de solucionar esto?. Soy bastante nuevo con este tema de `sockets`. De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!.

**Actualización:**

Logré resolver el problema de la estética, haciendo que se vea "bonito" la salida de la terminal, mediante un `.decode('utf-8')` a los datos recibidos del `socket` servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Cómo se haría para poder imprimir de forma "normal" por así decirlo,
>   la salida de la terminal?

Lo que se imprime es una cadena de bytes, que es lo que subprocess retorna y lo que recibes del server como tal. Para que se vea "normal" debes decodificar esa cadena usando la codificación adecuada. Puedes usar el argumento `universal_newlines=True` o `text=True` (alias en Python >=3.7) de `subprocess.run` para indicar a Python que use   codificación del sistema para decodificar la cadena de bytes que le llega y la convierta en una cadena UTF-8. Pero **no tienes garantizado que un subproceso dado retorne en una codificación dada o use la del sistema**, por lo que esto puede fallar.

> al ejecutar muchos comandos ocurre un error. `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`.

Esto se debe a que tu cliente intenta enviar datos al servidor cuando este ha cerrado la conexión. Pero, ¿por qué?. Si te fijas has intentado que subprocess ejecute `cd`, **`cd` no es un subproceso, es una funcionalidad de la shell**. Esto causa una excepción y el servidor termina su ejecución, cerrando con ello el socket en su lado. Si quieres usar comandos propios de la shell debes usar **shell=True** en **subproces.run** . Esto hace que cualquier comando se ejecute a través de la terminal en vez de lanzar un nuevo subproceso directamente (con todo lo que implica en cuanto a sintaxis y seguridad).

Otra cosa que deberías considerar es que en tu cliente (también en el server) lees 2024 bytes solamente, esto puede  ser suficiente o no. Nada te asegura que cierto subproceso genere una salida más extensa, en cuyo caso te dejas por leer parte de ella, la cual será leída en la próxima llamada a `recv` o incluso puedes terminar con el buffer lleno (cuyo tamaño depende del sistema) y `send` bloqueado en el lado del servidor. Deberías asegurate de leer todos los bytes enviados por el servidor. Lo mismo se aplica al servidor, si consideras que se pueden llegar a enviar comando que superen los 1024 bytes que le has asignado a `recv` en el lado del servidor.

Con todo lo comentado, algo así debería valerte:

### Servidor

```
import subprocess
import socket


def run_command(command):
    try:
        process = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True, shell=True)
        return process.stdout.encode("utf-8")
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e).encode("utf-8")

skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
skt.bind(('localhost', 9999))

skt.listen(5)

while True:
    client_socket, addr = skt.accept()

    while True:
        received = client_socket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        res = run_command(received)
        if not res: # cd por ejemplo no retorna nada
            res = b"\n"
        client_socket.send(res)
```

### Cliente

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('localhost', 9999))
BUFF_SIZE = 2024

while True:
    client_socket.send(
        input('>> ').encode('utf-8')
    )

    buff = []
    while True:
        received = client_socket.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
        buff.append(received.decode("utf-8"))
        if len(received) < BUFF_SIZE:
            break
    received = "".join(buff)
    print(received)

client_socket.close()
```

---

Una pequeña observación sobre llamar a `cd` en el subproceso, esto jamás va a cambiar el el directorio de trabajo del server, simplemente llama a la shell, ejecuta `cd` y cierra la shell, sin más. Ten en cuenta que puedes usar ssh vía subprocess, o usar paramiko, fabric, etc

No uses nunca `str.split`  para convertir la cadena con el comando a la lista con los argumentos separados para pasarla a `subprocess.run/Popen`. Esto es inseguro usa [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) en su lugar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!  Por cierto que hace exactamente `universal_newlines=True` o `text=True`?

Comment: Como comento, indica que la salida del subproceso (que es siempre de tipo bytes) debe codificarse usando la codificación por defecto del sistema y retornar una cadena (`str`). Cuando pasas este parámetro por tanto `process.stdout` retorna una cadena de texto (`str`) y no una cadena de bytes. No obstante como comento esto puede fallar si el subproceso retorna algo sin usar la codificación del sistema , especialmente en windows...

Comment: Ok ok, y cual seria la diferencia entre `universal_newlines=True` y `text=True`? Según veo preferiste utilizar `text=True` en ves de  `universal_newlines=True`.

Comment: Si la codificación falla, el servidor no terminará inesperadamente como te pasaba antes al usar cd, simplemente enviará el texto con la excepción al cliente (por eso entre otras cosas está ese try ahí).

Comment: La diferencia entre `universal_newlines=True` y `text=True` es ninguna (son el mismo argumento realmente), `text` se ha introducido en Python 3.7 como alias de `universal_newlines` ,  el cual para ser sinceros no indica con su nombre que es lo que verdaderamente hace este argumento, mientras que `text` es más claro (convertir la salida de bytes a texto ).

Comment: Ahhh ok ok. Muchas gracias por resolver mis dudas! Saludos!!